# ListView.getChildAt() getting child which are not on the screen

Tags: java, android, android-widget

hi i have an expandable listview and its going to scroll when i increase expanded it.and then i try to retrieve all the child but its giving me children which are currently on screen. how can i get the children which are not on the screen.
http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/7543f93b105c156e?fwc=1
i read this query but not understand how to override the getview method for getting those element.my getgroupview method is like this.

```
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parent) {
            View v;
            v=convertView;
            if(v==null)
             {LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
             v = vi.inflate(R.layout.group, null);
             }
        return v;}
```

what modification should i do for getting other child

Answer (score 1):

> how can i get the children which are not on the screen

You can't. They do not exist. `ListView` and `ExpandableListView` recycle rows.

Comment: if i have to check the number of checkboxes that are checked in list view then how to proceed.

Comment: @user819814: Have your rows implement the `Checkable` interface and use the built-in checked-items support in `ListView`.